# Import po-files using Drush

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n

I have about 20 sites that have a common translation. I don't want to go into admin of each site each time the po-file is updated.

Is it possible to import a po-file using Drush?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a way to do this using Drush and [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update).

1. Install Localization Update  `drush en l10n_update`
2. Configure a local path for po-files (admin/config/regional/language/update)
3. Configure automatic updates from remote servers or just local sources

Now you can put your own po-files in a local path (for example sites/all/translations). If you have translations for your own module then you name it according to this naming convention:

modulename-version.language.po

So a Swedish po-file for 'my_module', version 7.x-1.1 would be named:

my_module-7.x-1.1.sv.po

Now you have everything setup and you can start updating your sites translation with Drush:

```
drush l10n-update-refresh # Looks for new po-files
drush l10n-update # Updates translations
```

Comment: I couldn't get this really work. I have exported the translations in a po-file using the UI. It was named as `de.po` for German. I've renamed it to my modules name and appended it the version of my module like: `controller-7.x-1.0.de.po`. Pushed it with git and executed the drush commands. But it doesn't detect my newly pushed po-file and says 'All translations up to date'. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to place the po file in the directory configured by l10n_update as a source, typically sites/all/translations

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Watch out! If you want to use this method for custom local modules, your .info file must have the [`project` property](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#project), otherwise the module will be ignored completely.

Comment: One last detail, with the 2.2 version, I had to specify  `--mode=overwrite` when running `drush l10n-update`, otherwise the modifications in my .po file would not be taken into account (even if `mode` is already set to `overwrite` in the backend).

Comment: @GuillaumeBois Question has been asked for D8 here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253332/import-your-own-interface-translations-automatically-during-profile-or-module-in

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there's no way to do it with Drush but you can use the [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module.

You could also [try using Selenium IDE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25775/5147) or a Selenium script if you have a lot of sites.  This is the best solution I was able to come up with for getting translations as an exportable.

- I say there's no way to do it with Drush because I [opened a feature request in the issue queue a few weeks ago](http://drupal.org/node/1491072) and it was closed as "won't fix" with the reason that the maintainers think such a command should be tested in the i18n or other modules first before integrating it into the Drush trunk.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the drush module [Drush Language Commands](https://drupal.org/project/drush_language) has support for importing and exporting po files.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the [Potx Exportable](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx_exportables)s module.

It exposes Drush command `drush potx-import-all`

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Does the module have Drush support too? The OP is asking for a way to do it with Drush.

Answer (score 1):

For those who lands here many years later, the same commands for Drush 9 are:

1. [drush locale:check](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/locale/locale:check/)
2. [drush locale:update](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/locale/locale:update/)