# Import your own interface translations automatically during profile or module installation

Tags: 8

I have been trying to import my custom interface translation during profile installation using a .po file that is put inside the translations folder in my custom module. After running:

> drush locale-update && drush cr

All I get is community translations which are not accurate sometimes (no translation is imported from my .po file).

How can I import translations only from my local .po file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To import your own translations you should use the [interface translation properties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.4.x) on your module.

I'm using a folder **`translations`** in my modules where my language files like **`de.po`** or **`fr.po`** can be found. To load the translations you have to insert the following lines into your *example_module.info.yml*:

```
'interface translation project': example_module
'interface translation server pattern': modules/custom/example_module/translations/%language.po
```

And to update your translations use this:

```
drush locale-check && drush locale-update && drush cr
```

EDIT:
To update existent translations you should take a look at the settings page (/admin/config/regional/translate/settings):

[image]

You can try to use local translation files only or to overwrite any existing translation.

Comment: Thanks, this works but not exactly what I wanted. I prefer to override the provided translations (community translations) with my own translations.

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY have you tested a different import behavior? I've updated my answer with some information about available interface translation settings.

Answer (score 2):

Just import your own custom translations after importing the official ones:

```
drush locale:update -y
drush locale:import de ../translations/custom-translations.de.po --type=customized --override=all -y
```

you could do this in an update.sh after site install has run.
Check the flags like --override=all

Comment: I understand that the most voted answer is the way to go for a contrib module, but for a custom, internal-use-only module this is certainly much simpler.