# How to localize your own contrib module

Tags: i18n-l10n

Things have changed since I last localized a Drupal contrib module of mine. In D9/10, having a `translations` folder with `.po` files no longer seems to be the usual route. Yes, it can be done for local custom modules by specifying the location in the `info.yml` but I'm looking for a solution for regular, d.o hosted contrib modules. Right now I don't even need many languages, just one, the (Commerce) module in question applies to a single country, so the translation should obviously come directly for anybody installing the module.

I'm aware of [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273328/automatically-importing-module-provided-translations-during-installation) but it's unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some perseverance, I succeeded. The required steps are partly as described in the linked other question, have your `.po` files in a `translations` folder inside your module. But instead of adding the fixed path to the `info.yml` file, use the following hook in your `.module`:

```
function MODULE_locale_translation_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  $folder = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getPath('MODULE');
  $projects['MODULE'] = [
    'info' => [
      'interface translation server pattern' => $folder . '/translations/%language.po',
    ],
  ];
}
```

You may use a different naming scheme for the files, I decided the language code was enough for me.

This way, it will be loaded from the actual folder, no matter whether it's in `custom` or not.